# get a variable value inside double qoutes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eventhough i referred many answers related to this question i couldn't solve my issue.
my js is as follows

```
var currenteffect= $('#test').val();
    //alert(currenteffect);
jQuery('#wowslider-container1').wowSlider({effect:currenteffect, prev:"", next:"", duration: 20*100, delay:20*100, width:960, height:360, autoPlay:true, autoPlayVideo:false, playPause:false, stopOnHover:false, loop:false, bullets:true, caption: true, captionEffect:"fade", controls:true, responsive:1, fullScreen:false, onBeforeStep:0, images:0 });
```

I need to get the value of currenteffect inside double qoutes like

effect:"fly".

Can anyone help me

Comment: Why, it shouldn't matter as long as `currenteffect` is the string `"fly"` ?

Comment: no the value of the field **test** changes.

Comment: what does it alert when  you do this? `alert(currenteffect);`

Comment: the alert box is not popping up.:-(

Comment: change this: `//alert(currenteffect);` to this `alert(currenteffect);` if the alert doesnt pop then, then your problem is somwhere else

Comment: run a test, hardcode the value of currenteffect: `var currenteffect = "fly";` see if that works, then most likely the problem is in the value of `#test`

Comment: @ Sergio Alen-k.i found a small mistake..now it is popping up **fly**.but the slider is still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
effect:currenteffect
```

Passing it like this should be just fine, you don't need double quotes, check other things, there might be problem somewhere else if your slider is not working or if you are not getting effect that you want.

If you still want double quotes, here you go

```
effect:'\"'+currenteffect+'\"'
```

Comment: I have tried it but the slider is not working without that double qoutes and working fine with the double qoutes

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @VimalS try this effect:'\"'+currenteffect+'\"' as suggested in my answer.

Comment: @VimalS you said alert(currenteffect); not popping up, there should be another problem, check browser console.

Comment: @NikunjSardhara-it is popping up now..but slider is not working

Comment: @NikunjSardhara-you was right about the double qoutes.there was no need of double qoutes.my problem was solved when i refreshed the js file source code..:-P..Thanks Nikunj

Comment: @VimalS Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript String() function like this `String(currenteffect)`

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
var a = "asdfasd"; 
console.log('"'+a+'"');
```